# Replace intents for notification within app

Tags: java, android, android-intent

Intents are taking too long to be process in my app. Is there a better way I can tell different elements of my app that something has happened? For example I use:

```
Intent i = new Intent("com.ftx.player_died");
```

I listen for that intent on two different places in my app. I would not like to make the same call twice.

```
Inventory.playerDied(true);
NotificationBar.playerDied(true);
```

Doesn't scale nicely.

Is there something I can use that is faster than intents but that I don't make same call twice or three times?

Comment: is you trollin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [LocalBroadcastManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) or[EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus) is not only faster the normal `BroadcastManager`, but also is private to your app (that means other application cant listen to your `Intent` action)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of factors. It is needed to see of your project to give a piece of advice.
But in some cases it is possible to use usual `interface` that declared and shared in the static `Application` class.